# Vue 3 - Setting the type for a component and its props when used as function parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

In Vue 3, I'm creating a function that will accept an instance of a component and props to pass through. I'm also using TypeScript and was wondering if I can type those parameters. For example, the function would be something like:

```
const example = (component, props) => {
  //
};
```

So my questions would be:

1. How can I specify a type for a component instance? These are not always going to be the same component, but would at least be components that are used for a similar purpose.
2. Would there be a way for me to specify the type for the props and confine it to the props that would be for the first parameter (the component)?

Comment: For the first question, you can import your component and then use it as a type like that: `(component: typeof YourComponent, props) => {}`. I don't really understand your second question

Comment: Thank you. For the second question, the context is that I'm iterating through some objects, and I'm going to pass the component value into the "Component" component. So something like `<Component :is="component" v-bind="props"/>`. So for this function, I'd like to make the `props` type so that they're the props defined for the corresponding component. The idea would be to ensure that the expected props are passed through and ideally get some type hinting. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: A very interesting question, I like it, I'm trying out some code, I hope I could find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use many feature provided by typescript and the `Component` type from vue to achieve your proper typing, make a generic type that extends the `Component` then infers the component options/props using `infer`, use Partial to make them optional :

```js
import type { Component } from "vue";

function example<T extends Component>
(Comp: T, props: T extends Component<infer P> ? Partial<P> : never) {
 //....
  }

example(Alert, { variant: "success"})
```

**Note:** this also infers the attributes and component instance utilities

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Yeah, I was not familiar with `infer` and it's usage, so that's something for me to read more about too.